# What is/are the earliest first-hand account of a sex worker?

Tags: 20th-century, 19th-century, women, sexuality, prostitution

I was just reading [*Hell's Belles: Prostitution, Vice, and Crime in Early Denver*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0870816330) by Clark Secrest. I can't find the part now (it's not that important), but he comments that we have no surviving diary of a sex worker in Denver of the era (~1860-1910). This made me wonder about *any* early surviving firsthand accounts of sex workers.

So far, the only *legitimate* account I can find (pre-1950) is that of [Maimie Pinzer](https://hollisarchives.lib.harvard.edu/repositories/8/resources/5498). You can read an intriguing review of the book [HERE](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41279523) (Note: sign up for a free account and you get free access to a lot of their articles). I have purchased [that book](https://www.abebooks.com/9781558611436/Maimie-Papers-Letters-Ex-Prostitute-Helen-1558611436/plp) and am awaiting its delivery.

The Maimie papers, which were letters between an ex-prostitute and a novelist, cover the early part of the 20th century. Further, I am also aware of [Alice: Memoirs of a Barbary Coast Prostitute](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1597143618) and [MADELEINE:AN AUTOBIOGRAPHY](https://digital.library.upenn.edu/women/madeleine/madeleine/madeleine.html); however, it is my understanding that because these (and other) alleged sex-worker autobiographies/memoirs do not originate from a manuscript, only typescripts, their origins are doubtful.

I came across [this short story](http://ainofall2019.blog.sbc.edu/2019/09/09/the-diary-of-a-storyville-sex-worker/), which I, at first, took as real, but am now convinced is false. Also, I am aware of the fraudulent nature of [Nell Kimball: Her Life as an American Madam](https://www.nysoclib.org/blog/frauds-stacks#:%7E:text=Strange%20Story%20of-,Nell%20Kimball,-In%201970%2C%20Macmillan), which somehow slipped past Clark Secrest in his book, as he says:

> Nell Kimball’s supposedly autobiographical Nell Kimball, Her Life as an American Madam, Stephen Longstreet, ed. (New York: Macmillan, 1970), is a captivating and earthy read, and in the absence of evidence to the contrary, I have cautiously assumed here that it is genuine.

There is [a JSTOR article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3786441) on it, but you need JPASS. It is referenced in the above debunking of it.

So, my question is are there any firsthand accounts of sex workers earlier than this,or  alternatively, around this same time that are believed to be legitimate? My hope is to read one of a century earlier, or possibly even earlier from American history. As a side note, are there any surviving firsthand accounts of sex workers from Ancient history, such as Greece or Rome? Thanks.

Comment: How did you miss [*The Happy Hooker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Happy_Hooker) (1971) by [Xavier Hollander.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xaviera_Hollander)?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Because he's looking for pre-1950 texts?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens ideally, I am looking for pre-20th century texts. The Happy Hooker, which I did come across, is much later than I am interested in.

Comment: I'm rather surprised there are no surviving accounts (at least in retelling) of classical Greece period Heterae. Or (less likely) Geishas

Comment: What is a sex worker?  [The Memoirs of Harriette Wilson: Written by Herself](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/43617/43617-h/43617-h.htm) was published in 1825 and there must be earlier such accounts from courtesans.

Comment: @DVK - I think that Geishas' accounts are far more probable than anything from Ancient Greece. Do we have *any* feminine voice from ancient Greece  beside Sapho? - Japanese classic Geishas last as late as to meet with modern literary trends, like memoirs, of 19th and 20th century.

Comment: @User65535 That is certainly helpful, I will be reading that soon. She certainly represents an extreme exception to the typical prostitute, though. I was more interested in more marginalized perspectives, though, again, this does help.